# Ordered checklist for learning Mathematics for Data Science

Tags: self-learning

I want to understand and teach Mathematics for Data Science. I know for Data Science I need to understand:

- Probability
- Statistics
- Linear Algebra
- Calculus

But I want a quick refresh of everything from the very basics and then go to the above mentioned concepts in some order. But I don't know in what order I can go. I need something like an ordered checklist to ensure that I understood the fundamentals before going on to advanced concepts.

Comment: You want to teach? On what level (university, business school, highschool, ...)? Can you become a teacher only from self-learning, aren't there any requirements on courses you have to take, for example?

Comment: @DirkLiebhold I want to develop a course, mathematics for Machine Learning and publish that in Udemy. I'm a Software Engineer so I have some experience in problem solving mathematically. But still in not confident, I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding "for Data Science" to the title, to make it more specific.

Comment: It is hard to answer this question without knowing your background, your time frame, and the depth to which you want to learn the material. Are you in need of a quick 2-week refresher of algebra and trig, or do you need to cover that material much more slowly? For someone who has already had some of the Calculus and Linear Algebra in college (which will be true of most people who were CS majors), a month of study should be enough to get up to speed on those topics. Others might need to spend a year on just that. Similar remarks hold for probability and stats.

Answer (score 3):

This link (compiled by Wale Akinfaderin) may help: 
["The Mathematics of Machine Learning"](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-mathematics-of-machine-learning-894f046c568).

---

[image: PieChart]

---

The MIT course ["Mathematics of Machine Learning"](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-657-mathematics-of-machine-learning-fall-2015/) (Philippe Rigollet) illustrates what might be called advanced math for machine learning,
pretty much assuming as prerequisites what is in the pie chart above.

Comment: What a cool answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question but I mentioned that "I want a quick refresh of everything from the very basics and then go to the above mentioned concepts" this might sounds silly but what I actually means is 1st "Fundamentals of Mathematics itself" and then "Fundamentals of Mathematics for Data Science"

Comment: @bkmagnetron: Sounds like you are asking for a list of all high-school math, up to pre-calculus and at least some calculus. Those topics would be prerequisites for the math needed for data science.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke what I looking for is something like this https://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard but purely mathematics where the link contains some programming and some other stuffs.

Comment: magnetron (what is the BK for?  Know magnetrons from microwave heater design).:

Comment: BK:  Try this Schaum's (used version of the 58 edition is best):  https://www.amazon.com/Theory-problems-first-college-mathematics/dp/B0007DPVM2 for all precalc.

Comment: @guest: He will only be automatically notified of your comments if you use "@bkmagnetron."

Comment: OK.  May use that in future for staler threads.  Figure he is watching this one, though.